# fadeIn as callback function after fadeOut doenst work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, delay, fadeout

In my HTML a#navInnerMapR and a#navInnerMapL are contained within div#navTwo.

The following code is within a function. When called, I need the function to fadeOut any visible links in div#navTwo, pause for a moment, and then fadeIn a#navInnerMapR.

```
$('div#navTwo a').fadeOut(200, function() {
    $('a#navInnerMapR').delay(100).fadeIn(200);
});
```

The code fades out the links but doesn't fade anything in. I thought that they delay would only start once the fadeOut finishes, however changing the delay value to 1000 makes it sometimes work but its very buggy. Thanks

UPDATE Here is a fiddle showing that the hidden link starts to be shown before the visible is hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/d9QKr/5/

UPDATE Apologies, my question doesnt include the full details of what I need to achieve. I simplified it as I thought I just had some sort of sytax issus that could be easily fixed.

div#navTwo actually contains 3 links. At any point (other than the delay before animations run) only 1 link is visible. I need to be able to call a function that will hide either of the other 2 links that are being shown, and then show a#navInnerMapR.

Different events will call this function, so either of the 2 links that arn't a#navInnerMapR may be visible. Thanks

UPDATE I think this fiddle illustrates the issue. Ive created 2 div.nav's to illustrate different states. Ive hidden different links with inline CSS in each one. JavaScript will be showing and hiding the links in my div repeatedly, so the same div will look like each example at different times.

Ive created 2 triggers to illustrate that different events will need to call the function. When you click on a trigger you can see the issue with both examples. The visible divs are not hidden before the a.one is shown. Thanks for your patience!

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/dYvMS/24/

Interesting point, if I change $('.nav a.one').fadeIn(1000); to an alert, the alert fires multiple times! No idea why this would be the case!

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/uCZjH/1/). Btw, you don't need a `delay` because the callback will be called once after the `fadeOut` animation is over.

Comment: It looks like the hidden link starts to be shown before the visible one is hidden http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/d9QKr/

Comment: What are you trying to achive? How do you want it to work? For ex: What should happen when Right linked is clicked? Try http://jsfiddle.net/skram/d9QKr/6/ <- Is this something you want?

Comment: Yes thats what I want but I need the animation in a function I can call as clicking different things will make it happen. Why does my code not work like yourse? Thanks

Comment: Technically I want a delay in between the fading out and fading in so this is more what I want, but like said I need to be able to call the function with multiple events. The events also have various conditionals to them firing which is why its importnat to separate things out. http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/tbAF7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated answer based on your below comment,

> Yes this works as I need, but im not sure it will work for my actual
>   page. Sorry for my question not being detailed enough. The code
>   example I gave is simplified. In the actual page their are 3 links
>   within div#navTwo, at any time only one of them will be visible. I
>   need to be able to call a function that hides any links and shows a
>   specific one, but either one of the other 2 links in div#navTwo may be
>   visible. Thanks

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/tbAF7/2/)

**HTML:** Added class to all links inside navTwo

```
<div id="navTwo">
    <a href="#" id="navInnerMapR" class="links">Right</a>
    <a href="#" id="navInnerMapL" class="links">Left</a>
    <a href="#" id="navInnerMapM" class="links">Middle</a>
    <a href="#" id="navInnerMapU" class="links">Upper</a>
    <a href="#" id="navInnerMapLW" class="links">Lower</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.links').click(function() {
       showHide($(this));
});

function showHide($this) {    
    $this.fadeOut(1000, function() {
         $('#navTwo a').not($this).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
```

---

I think I understood what you need. Try below DEMO and let me know if that is what you want,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/tbAF7/1/)

```
$('#navInnerMapR').click(function() {
       runMeR($(this));
});
$('#navInnerMapL').click(function() {
       runMeL($(this));
});

function runMeR($this) {    
    $this.fadeOut(1000, function() {
         $('a#navInnerMapL').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
function runMeL($this) {    
    $this.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('a#navInnerMapR').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes this works as I need, but im not sure it will work for my actual page. Sorry for my question not being detailed enough. The code example I gave is simplified. In the actual page their are 3 links within div#navTwo, at any time only one of them will be visible. I need to be able to call a function that hides any links and shows a specific one, but either one of the other 2 links in div#navTwo may be visible. Thanks

Comment: If I add a 3rd link to your fiddle its not hidden

Comment: @jdln You need to elaborate on what you need with specific information. For ex: what should happen when I click on trigger one? Please be more specific and also try starting new question instead of updating the existing question.

Comment: This fiddle should demonstrate the issue. The visible divs are not hidden before the a.one is shown.  http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/dYvMS/24/

Comment: @jdln I saw that demo and it was confusing. Your code is working as expected and there is nothing wrong with that code. In you DEMO, `$('.nav a')` will select all the links (6 of them) inside both div. You are trying to fade them all and show them inside callback which is going to mess up the animation. As I mentioned in my previous comment, be more specific on what you want. If you let us know what you want then we can modify that code to help you. It is very hard to assume what you want and look at that code.

Comment: Sorry, what I want is for any visible links to fade out, and then after that for a.one to fade in. Thanks

Comment: @jdln Try this http://jsfiddle.net/skram/dYvMS/26/ and Let me know if that is something you want.

Comment: Ah, turns out I just needed it to be a:visible. Thanks you so much!

Comment: If it lets me start a bounty in a few days ill send you some point. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, You need the function to fadeOut any visible links in div#navTwo, pause for a moment, and then fadeIn a#navInnerMapR (not other links, only a#navInnerMapR).

```
$('#navTwo a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().children().each(function(i){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('a#navInnerMapR').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});​
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d9QKr/9/).

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was detailed enough to explain what I actually need. Ive updated it. Thanks